# Pytube, urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python, pytube

I just installed 'pytube' and i keep getting the same error every time i run my code.non of the methods i saw on here help to solve it and i am not exactly sure what to do...would appreciate any help.Thanks!

(The code):

```
from pytube import YouTube

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"

yt = YouTube(url)

print(yt.title)
```

(The error):

```
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Is this an attempt to rick roll stack overflow?

Comment: maybe YouTube changed something on page and now it need changes in module - and you have to wait for newer version.

Comment: @RomanCzerwinski not really put i guess it worked :D

Comment: @furas do you have the same when running the same cod ?

Comment: I have the same problem with the same code. I checked also with different URL. And I checked if there is update for this module. I even get example from [documentation](https://pytube.io/en/latest/). Always the same error.

Comment: I also checked when was released the latest version - [pytube](https://pypi.org/project/pytube/) - and it was Jul 21, 2021 (3 days ago). And I checked [issuses](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues) and other people also have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

See [issuses](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues) on `PyTube` repo - other people also have the same problem.

It seems `YouTube` changed something on server and now module also needs some changes and you have to wait for newer version.

---

From time to time you can visit [PyTybe on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pytube/) to see if there is newer version.

Or simply from time to time you can try to install newer version using `--update` or `-U`

```
pip install -U pytube
```

Comment: ok appreciate the all of the help, do you have any suggestion for similar libraries?

Comment: [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme) ? It is created in Python. You can run it in console as normal program or you can use in code `import youtube_dl` - see [embeding](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl)